# Callout in test method not returning mock response

Tags: unit-test, callout, httprequest, httpcalloutmock, http

I am trying to write a test class for testing an HTTP callout. Test class compiles without errors. However, I am not getting the mock response inside.
Below is the relevant parts of my code.

**TestClass**

```
   @isTest

public static void testCRCampaignsCalloutSuccess() {
  CRAccount__c testCrAccount = 
   (CRAccount__c)SmartFactory.createSObject('CRAccount__c',true);
    testCrAccount.namedCredential__c ='TestNamedCredential';
    insert testCrAccount;

    Campaign testCampaign = (Campaign)SmartFactory.createSObject('Campaign',true);
    testCampaign.crId__c = '123456';
    insert testCampaign;
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new TestMockingCrCampaigns());
      List<DO_Campaign> crCampaignsList = ImportCampaignsAngularPoCCntrl.getCrCampaigns(testCrAccount.namedCredential__c);
      system.assert(!crCampaignsList.isEmpty());
      }
```

**Controller Method**

```
 public static List<DO_Campaign> getCRCampaigns(String namedcredential)
{ 
  HttpRequest sfRequest = new HttpRequest();
     HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('http://api.salesforce.com/foo/bar');
    req.setMethod('GET');
    Http h = new Http();
    system.debug('***RequestToSend***'+req);
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    system.debug('***Response***'+response);
    List<DtoManager.CampaignDto> receivedCampaignDto = 
      (List<DtoManager.CampaignDto>) JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),  List<DtoManager.CampaignDto>.class);
             if(receivedCampaignDto != null && !receivedCampaignDto.isEmpty()){
                List<DO_Campaign> campaignsReceived = doManager.generateCampaigns(receivedCampaignDto);
    return campaignsReceived;
}
```

**TestMockClass**

```
 @isTest
  global class TestMockingCrCampaigns implements HttpCalloutMock {

global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    system.debug('**Inside TestMockingCrCampaigns**');
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
     res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     res.setBody('[{"id":"502097","name": "CreatingCampaignfromCR","stamp": 1491545738,"last_mailing": 1494914539,"last_changed": 1491545814,"is_locked": false},{"id": "502099","name": "CreatingGroupviaAPIPostman","stamp": 1491483714,"last_mailing": 0,"last_changed": 0,"is_locked": false}]');
     res.setStatusCode(200);
     return res;
   }
  }
```

I am getting debug till **RequestToSend** . Not the **Response**. Cannot get the debug statement inside the respond method of **TestMockingCrCampaigns**.The feature works fine without any errors outside test class.

Comment: Try putting your method call line in test class between Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() once.

Comment: @NitishSinghal You should add that as an answer, perhaps with a link to the docs.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue by following in the exact steps as in https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html. I could not figure out the error in my approach though